# New record appears at bottom of table?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor application that is displaying records in a table using the code below:

```
Template.records.helpers({
  trackingData: function() {
    return Tracking.find({},{$sort: {fullDate: -1}})
  }
})
```

And

```
<table>
  ...
  {{#each trackingData}}
     <tr class="record" id="{{_id._str}}">
     ...
  {{/each}}
  ...
</table>
```

And

```
Meteor.publish('tracking', function(filter, offset) {
    var records = Tracking.find(filter,{
      sort: {fullDate: -1}, 
      limit:10, 
      skip: offset*10
    });
    return records
  });
```

For some reason, when my new record is added it always shows up at the bottom of the table.  Based on the sorting I have in place the new record should show on top.  What's odd is that when I refresh the page the record stays on the bottom **but** when I stop my app and restart it - the record shows at the top like it should.  What might I be missing that would cause this sort of odd sorting behavior?

Comment: You need to sort the collection in the client code as well as in the server

Comment: @Mikkel - I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`Tracker.flush()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-flush) or similar:

> Normally, when you make changes (like writing to the database), their impact (like updating the DOM) is delayed until the system is idle. This keeps things predictable — you can know that the DOM won’t go changing out from under your code as it runs. It’s also one of the things that makes Meteor fast.
>
> `Tracker.flush` forces all of the pending reactive updates to complete. For example, if an event handler changes a Session variable that will cause part of the user interface to rerender, the handler can call flush to perform the rerender immediately and then access the resulting DOM

Basically, the [`Collection.find`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) operation returns a cursor that is generally only computed once.

The topic was covered by [this blog](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) as well:

> When you publish documents to the client, they are merged with other
> documents from the same collection and rearranged into an in-memory
> data store called minimongo. The key word being rearranged.
>
> Many new meteor developers have a mental model of published data as
> existing in an ordered list. This leads to questions like: "I
> published my data in sorted order, so why doesn't it appear that way
> on the client?" That's expected. There's one simple rule to follow:
>
> If you need your documents to be ordered on the client, sort them on
> the client. Sorting in a publish function isn't usually necessary
> unless the result of the sort changes which documents are sent (e.g.
> you are using a limit).
>
> You may, however, want to retain the server-side sort in cases where
> the data transmission time is significant. Imagine publishing several
> hundred blog posts but initially showing only the most recent ten. In
> this case, having the most recent documents arrive on the client first
> would help minimize the number of template renderings.